# How to reference current object in XAML

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I cant' figure out how to reference the current instance object defined by the XAML file in the XAML file.

I have a converter that I want to send in the current instance as the parameter object.

```
{Binding Path=<bindingObject>, Converter={x:Static namespace:Converter.Instance}, ConverterParameter=this}
```

In this code this is converted to a string instead of a reference to the current instance object.

Thanks

John

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#current_record_pointers), you can use the "/" to indicate the current item. You can then navigate up and down the tree as needs be using the following type syntaxes:

```
<Button Content="{Binding }" />
<Button Content="{Binding Path=/}" />
<Button Content="{Binding Path=/Description}" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Technically, the ConverterParameter is not a DependencyProperty, so you can't bind to it.  It would be nice to do a ConverterParameter={Binding ElementName=this}, but you can't bind to a non-dependency property.

But, someone figure it out how to do it [here](http://rauscheronline.de/item/2008/08/using-databinding-in-a-converterparameter).  This is however a bit complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [`RelativeSource` markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599.aspx)? You can use `Self` there.